# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, syntax, syntax-error

I'm trying to install a WordPress plugin and getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in /home/myname/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/plugin.php on line 588
```

This is the line of code it's referring to:

```
} = "\n\n<p>Do you constantly dream of writing a screenplay?  Do you have a killer idea that would look great on the big screen?  Do you dream of being the next Tarantino?</p>\n<p><i>If so - the solution you have been looking for is finally here!</i></p>\n<p>In <b>\"Where To Start - How To Become A Hollywood Script Writer" < / b > youaregoingtolearnexactlyhowtowriteascreenplay - and howtocreateamassivedemand
```

Does anyone know what's going on?  The plugin was originally obfuscated so I had to get it decoded to be able to make some changes but can't figure out what's causing this...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the missing \ before the " at this point:

```
Script Writer" </b>
```

So, it should be:

```
Script Writer\" </b>
```